# .htaccess redirect to a single page everytime, but keep same url for application reasons

Tags: .htaccess

I looked through other stack overflow questions and I couldn't find one that was my exact case.

I have tried writing several different .htaccess rewrite rules but I can't seem to get it working.

I need to do the following:

Original URL: testexample.com/tool/1

Needs to redirect to: textexample.com/tool/display.php

But the URL in the browser needs to stay : testexample.com/tool/1

Can anyone point me in the right direction for rules for this rewrite?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  !display\.php/?  [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^/([^/]+)/?.*/?  [NC]
RewriteRule .*  %1/display.php     [L]
```

Maps silently

`http://testexample.com/anything/folder` (Shown in the browser all the time)

To

`http://textexample.com/anything/display.php`